# What is the underlying mathematics behind law of mass action?

Tags: probability, derivatives, physics, chemistry, related-rates

When calculating reaction rates of of a chemical reaction, what is the reason taking product of concentration of chemicals (i. e. V+ = k[A][B]) instead addition (e.g. k[A] + k[B])?

Does this related to probability or which rule of derivation explains this?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps better suited for Chemistry.SE? Also, a quick google search will lead to this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6924/why-does-the-reaction-quotient-use-the-products-multiplications-of-reactants-a

Comment: It's a physical law. The only mathematics that applies is what you have written. Sometimes an equation can be derived from simpler expressions but those expressions will simply be descriptions of some fundamental property of the physical universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability is indeed one way to view this. Consider 2 independent chemicals A,B who react when *they are at the same place at the same time*. Assuming the distribution is homogeneous and independent, the probability of a certain molecule of type $A$ to be at a given position $x$ is the density $[A]$ times the volume $dx$, so the probability of both materials to react is proportional to $[A][B]$, as the events are independent. The 'orders' come from reactions when several molecules of each chemical are needed simultaneously, eg $2A+B\rightarrow [A]^2[B]$ since we need the probability of 2 molecules of $A$ to arrive independently for the interaction to occur.